# How do I reverse the bash history list?

Tags: bash, command-history

Example history:

```
$ history
1  whoami
2  pwd
3  ls
```

To get a reversed history list, I do:

```
$ history|tac
3  ls
2  pwd
1  whoami
```

But are there any better ways to do this, perhaps that needn't invoke another program, for those without tac installed, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the owner of a separate answer deleted it, I'll suggest:

```
history | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 5):

To list history in reverse order add `-rl` to `fc` command:

```
fc -rl
```

Obviously `fc -l` list in standard order. You can also specify the number of entries you want to see e.g. `fc -rl -10`.

Comment: This works, but it removes my HISTTIMEFORMAT from every line.

Comment: @EmmaV - the `-i` or flag is what you need to display the time format. Like so: `fc -rli`. `-E` and `-f` are alternative flags to `-i` if you prefer a different time format.